# Determine whether $g(x) = (x - 2)\lfloor x\rfloor$, is differentiable at $x_o = 2$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Determine whether $g(x) = (x - 2)\lfloor x\rfloor$, is differentiable at $x_o = 2$.

 So far I have.. $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x_o + h) - f(x_o)}{h} = lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(2-2+h)\lfloor 2 + h\rfloor - (2-2)\lfloor 2\rfloor}{h} = lim_{h\to 0}\lfloor 2 + h\rfloor$

$\lfloor 2 + 0\rfloor = 2$

 Am I on the right track? Any hints on what to do next?

Comment: You have replaced $x_0$ with $2$, but your question is whether it is differentiable at $x_0 = 0$.

Comment: Oh sorry I meant 2 the whole time. I'll fix that

Comment: Watch it: $$\;\lfloor 2+h\rfloor=\begin{cases}2&,\;\;h>0\\1&,\;\;h<0\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to 2^+}\frac{f(x)-f(2)}{x-2}=\lim_{x\to 2^+}\frac{(x-2)]\lfloor x\rfloor-0}{x-2}=\lim_{x\to 2^+}\frac{2(x-2)}{x-2}=2$$

$$\lim_{x\to 2^-}\frac{f(x)-f(2)}{x-2}=\lim_{x\to 2^-}\frac{(x-2)]\lfloor x\rfloor-0}{x-2}=\lim_{x\to 2^-}\frac{1\cdot(x-2)}{x-2}=1$$

Thus the limit defining the derivative at $\;x=2\;$ doesn't exist...

Answer (score 1):

So far, so good (although you have written $f(h)$ when you mean $f(x_0)$ in your statement of the derivative).

So, the derivative exists if $$\lim_{h\to 0}\lfloor 2+h\rfloor$$ exists. Try plotting this function as a function of $h$ over the interval $(-1,1)$ to see if it looks like the limit exists.  (Yes, $\lfloor 2+0\rfloor=2$, but that is beside the point when considering whether the *limit* exists).

Answer (score 1):

Informally, in an immediate left-neighborhood of $2$, the function is $(x-2)$. But in the immediate right-neighborhood of $2$, the function is $2(x-2)$. So the left-side slope and the right-side slope are different.

Comment: *Informally, in an ...* To me this seems just as formal as the other answers, and it's easier to swallow. However, DonAntonio's details are probably better suited for Brian.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Yeah, probably not the right word. I was referring to how I was making up terms like "left-neighborhood" and "right-side slope" which may not be formally defined (but easily could be).